# Error while hitting the Server from TEST Environment in mule HTTP connector

Tags: java, http, mule, anypoint-studio

I am able to Hit a particular server from my Local anypoint studio Mule flow and i am getting the response thru my local flow, but when i deploy the same Mule flow into a TEST environment i am unable to hit the server getting error message as "ERROR in sending HTTP I have tried setting "set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything" but didn't work and tried Increasing Connection Idle timeout and Response Time Out in HTTP Connector Configuration but no luck.

The error i am getting is below:

Exception stack is:

```
Error sending HTTP request. 
(org.mule.api.MessagingException)sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(null:-1)
  sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(null:-1)


org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnectorHandler.connectAsync(TCPNIOConnectorHandler.java:137)

  org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.connect(AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.java:91)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.connect(AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.java:56)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.ConnectionManager$AhcEndpoint.connect(ConnectionManager.java:280)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.connect(SingleEndpointPool.java:1155)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.take(SingleEndpointPool.java:787)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.MultiEndpointPool.take(MultiEndpointPool.java:592)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.ConnectionManager.openAsync(ConnectionManager.java:143)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:174)
  com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:506)
  com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:528)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:238)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:326)
  org.mule.mod`enter code here`ule.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:217)
  (21 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Comment: uncomment the line is the log4j2.xml to enable HTTP wire traffic (DEBUG level).
         <!-- Http Logger shows wire traffic on DEBUG. -->
        <!--AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG" /--> 

You should see more info now on what is happening.

Comment: @JoostD Thanks for ur response. i am using Mule community edition not the enterprise edition so can't debug connector flow, can u pls suggest me an alternative

Comment: Did you try JoosD suggestion? It doesn't seem to be an enterprise feature and it is not related to debugging a flow, though I'm not sure to what feature you are referring.

Comment: Also it looks like there should be more lines to the error. For example the error detail and the exception is missing. Paste a complete error please.

Comment: That error is using Mule 3, so the class to set in DEBUG level is `org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger`. This works in CE. However, that will log out HTTP traffic which I don't believe is going through here because you are getting a connection error to the host. It looks like the host address is not resolved properly from that environment. As @aled suggested, we need the entire error log using `-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true` to help further.